# Как с помощью PHP проверить данные из форм на пустоту?

Tags: php, mysql

Еще очень нужно знать как с помощью PHP проверить данные из форм на пустоту, так как при каждом обновление страницы (F5) добавляется пустая запись в базу данных mySQL?

Comment: Также интересно знать, то как Вы проверяете данные на дублирование? Чтобы в базе данных не было одинаковых записей...

Comment: Можно например одно поле в таблице БД сделать ключ типа PRIMARY. Но это только одно поле можно назначить. Можно в прямую проверку делать. Т.е сначала сделать запрос в таблицу, а потом проверка с тем, что мы имеем.

Comment: *Нужно* сделать PRIMARY. А можно — [UNIQUE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ избежать повторной отправки данных из формы, это редирект страницы саму на себя, в php это функция header("location: http://Сайт"); Если редирект исключить, то можно сделать в форме скрытое поле, например так: `<input type="hidden" name="rand" value="<?php mt_rand();?>" />`, Дальше в скрипте проверить эти данные на совпадение с этим параметром из сесси, если такого числа нет, то продолжать ( не забыв забить текущий ранд в сессию)

Comment: Пользователь открыл одну страницу сразу в 2-х вкладках. Как быть с `rand`?

Comment: Легко, $_SESSON['rand'][$_POST['r']] = true;
if($_SESSON['rand'][$_POST['r']])
Вот и всё

Comment: Если бы такая штука была, к примеру, здесь, на хешкоде, то мой файл сессии весил бы уже около 1 MiB. Но у [некоторых](http://hashcode.ru/users/?sort=%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) — свыше 50.

Я за ваш ответ по части переадресации, но `rand` — это, по-моему, жестоко.

Comment: Бывают случаи где редирект дорого обходится, можно в куки забить, а там размер - это проблема клиента

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = '';
if( empty( $var ) )
   return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
$name = isset($_GET['name'])?trim($_GET['name']):'';
if($name != '')
    echo 'Поле не пустое';
```

name - название поля. Можно попробывать и через функцию empty. Также обратите внимание, если у вас по умолчанию есть в поле value, то стоит его тоже кинуть в проверку.

Answer (score 1):

```
// error - массив с ошибками.
$error = array();
// length - максимально допустимая длина переменной.
$length = 255;

if ( isset($_POST['var']) && !empty($_POST['var']) ) {
    $var = htmlspecialchars($_POST['var']);
    $var = trim(substr($var,0,$length));
    if ( empty($var) ) {
        $error['var'] = 'Не определена';
    }
} else {
    $error['var'] = 'Не определена';
}

if ( empty($error) ) {
    echo 'it`s ok!'; 
} else {
    echo 'we got a problem!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя вот так разграничивать POST и GET.

Чтобы узнать, передавалось ли что-то, нужно проверить метод запроса:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    // ...
    }
```

Но после успешной обработки такого запроса (обычно под POST подразумевают, что какие-то данные поступят/перезапишут что-то) нельзя просто взять и продолжить работу. После обработки (например, после добавления комментария) нужно перенаправить клиента на эту же страницу, но по GET:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    $error = false;

    // ...

    if (!$error)
        {
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 303 /* или 301 */);
        die();
        }
    }
```

Вместо многоточия должна выполняться операция обработки поступивших данных и проверка их на ошибки (пустоту — в т.ч), в соответствие с чем переменная `$error` должна принимать какое-то «истинное» значение. Я, к примеру, прямо в нее и пишу текст ошибки:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    $error = array();

    if (!$_POST['name'])
        $error[] = 'Представься, будь любезен.';

    if (!$_POST['message'])
        $error[] = 'Ты забыл написать текст сообщения.';

    if (!$error)
        {
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 303 /* или 301 */);
        die();
        }
    else
        {
        echo '<p>'.implode('</p><p>', $error).'</p>';
        }
    }
```

Ну, почти так.